# How do I find all occurrences of a specific sentence within a string?

Tags: c#, regex, linq, substring

Let's say I had a string like this:

```
string source = "Today is friday! I'm am having trouble programming this. Today is friday! Tomorrow is saturday. Today is friday!"
```

I want to search through this string, grab all the sentences that say "Today is friday!", and create a new string with the sentences I just found.

The expected result from the above string is:

```
string output = "Today is friday!Today is friday!Today is friday!"
```

EDIT: LINQ is not mandatory.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? And why do you think LINQ is the right choice to solve your task?

Comment: Not sure what you want. If you want to check against one sentence each time, maybe it will be easier to just calculate number of its occurrences?

Comment: What do you want in case of a sentence like `I like programming and today is friday.`.  Do you want to capture the entire sentence or just the `today is friday` part?

Comment: What's the idea?  It was a `a OR b` question, you need to specify if you want result `a` or `b`.  As is, it's a little ambiguous.  Also, are you parsing something like a homework where strings are likely to have few punctuation marks or normal text, which is likely to have [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) and question marks separating your sentences?

Comment: I'd like to capture the entire sentance. I'm parsing a string block that could have any kind of input in it. (The string that I'm parsing) can come from many places, and therefore I can't predict what it's going to contain.

Comment: @1__ That's practially not possible.  Language is just so complex that you aren't realistically going to be able to tell what periods are ending a sentance, and what are ending abbreviations, just to name one of many difficulties you'll have.

Comment: @Servy Good call on abbreviations.  Generally punctuation mark followed by two spaces will be considered a different sentence, so he might be able to get away with splitting input on that.  However, reading chat logs or emails where standard punctuation goes out the window he's pretty SOL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a non-LINQ method of doing it:

```
string str = "Today is friday! I'm am having trouble programming this. Today is friday! Tomorrow is saturday. Today is friday!";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int index = 0;
do
{
    index = str.IndexOf("Today is friday!", index);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        sb.Append("Today is friday!");
        index++;
    }
} while (index != -1);

string repeats = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

There is actually no need to find the matches. Since you are creating a new string based on your search pattern it will suffice if you simply have a **count** of the occurrences of the search string. You can replace the Regex with a faster substring counting algorithm if you like.

```
string source = "Today is friday! I'm am having trouble programming this. Today is friday! Tomorrow is saturday. Today is friday!";
string searchPattern = "Today is friday!";
int count = Regex.Matches(source, searchPattern).Count;
string result = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(searchPattern, count));
```

Comment: It was just a bad example, there's a clarification in the comments.  This won't capture the sentences he wants though.

Answer (score 4):

### Regex

Find:

```
.*?(Today is friday).*?(?=\1|$)
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

### Explanation

```
.*?                 # match everything before an occurrence of the sentence
(Today is friday!)  # match the sentence
.*?                 # match everything after the sentence...
(?=\1|$)            # ...up to the next occurrence or end of the string
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, well the first thing you would need to do is make your one string into many. String.Split() should work here, no need for a Regex:

```
var sentences = inputString.Split('.','!');
```

Once you have the individual sentences, you just have to look for the ones that match the criteria:

```
var todayIsFridaySentences = sentences.Where(s=>s.Contains("Today is friday"));
```

... and then finally put them back together; if you absolutely must use Linq for this:

```
var ouputString = todayIsFridaySentences
                     .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (s,b) => b.Append(s))
                     .ToString();
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with cases where '.' or '!' aren't ending a sentence.  What about "Mr." or '!' used to denote "factorial".

Comment: Neither of those cases are present in the example and the OP didn't say they were concerns. Nobody ever said this solution worked in the general case. If it has to, then the solution becomes extremely difficult; sentences must be separated by two spaces (a standard that is becoming increasingly uncommon) or else one or more of these edge cases will slip by or cause legitimate sentence breaks to be ignored.

Comment: I personally like my code to work on more than just one same test input.  The OP stated the following in a comment to the question: ' I'm parsing a string block that could have any kind of input in it. (The string that I'm parsing) can come from many places, and therefore I can't predict what it's going to contain.'

Comment: Fair enough; then your response to that comment was accurate. It might be possible with an extremely complex lookbehind Regex (find the search substring, then look backward to find either the beginning of the string or the first letter after a period and one or more spaces not immediately prefaced by a known abbreviation, then forward to find the same) but I'm pretty sure any expression you create would fail some input designed specifically to test a weakness.