# search a String from file and gets its after and before text

Tags: c#, string, file-io

Hi there I'm new to c# and want to search a keyword from a file and if found i want to print the strings after and before that keyword plus the keyword with both of that strings as well. I know i have to first find the index of the keyword if its found and then try to get the string at index+1 of the keyword as well as index-1 of that keyword.

My sample data set is:

```
 (1) The amount of insurance or reinsurance exceeding an insurer's or reinsurer's 
 normal **capacity**
 inclusive of automatic reinsurance facilities. (2) A commitment by an insurer or 

 reinsurer above and
 beyond normal facilities or capacities.

 (1) Certain high-value bridges, tunnels, and fine art collections that are excluded 

 from an automatic
 reinsurance contract to permit specific handling of the **capacity** problem and to 

 release the reinsurer from
 the potential heavy accumulation of liability on any one risk. (2) A large, hazardous 

 risk on which
 insurance is difficult to place. (3) A large, attractive risk that is considered a    target 

 for competing
 insurance companies.
```

this is just a text file written so don't bother formatting!
the bold text denotes the word capacity i want the text before and after it;

Suppose I am being successful in finding the keyword as capacity now i want to print the strings before and after the capacity so the result should should give me

```
  **normal capacity
  capacity inclusive
  the capacity
  capacity problem**
```

my code is:

```
       private void openfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (text.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            err.SetError(text, "Needs to contain Text");
        }

        DialogResult result = open_dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            try
            {
                string file_name = open_dialog.FileName;
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file_name);

                String line;
                List<string> wordslist = new List<string>(count);

                using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(file_name))
                {

                    // read each line, ensuring not null (EOF)

                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line == String.Empty)
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wordslist.AddRange(line.Split(' '));
                            count += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (string str in wordslist)
                {
                    if (str==(text.Text))
                    {
                        int index = wordslist.IndexOf(text.Text);
                    Console.WriteLine("\ncapacity " + wordslist[index+1]);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + wordslist[index - 1]+" capacity");
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nERROR= " + ex);
            }
        }

    }
```

The Code works just find for only finding the only one set of words for me and for it only gives me:

```
     normal capacity
  capacity inclusive
```

What is the problem in my code so it shows all occurrences of capacity wherever it is and gives me the text after and before it!

Comment: you need to check that [index+1] is not bigger than the list of words and also that [index-1] is equeal or bigger than 0. Also what happes if the text to check has the word "capacity" follow by another "capacity" word ? is that posible ? how should the programa behave

Comment: no it is not possible and i need all pairs of capacity with all its after and before texts in the whole file!

Comment: user3154778 check my answer to see if that solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning index to the "first occurence of the word in the word list" with this instrucction

```
int index = wordslist.IndexOf(text.Text);
```

So I suggest you change that to this

```
int max ;
int index ;

max = wordslist.Count() ;

for (index = 0 ; index < max; index++)
{
    if (wordslist[index] == text.Text)
    {
        if(index - 1 > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + wordslist[index - 1]+ text.Text);
        }

        if(index + 1 < max)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + text.Text + " " + wordslist[index+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this was a problem anyhow you give me the problem clue hats off +1

Answer (score 1):

Besides your code, it is worth to notice that you can easily search through text using [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
capacity\s+\w+
```

and

```
\w+\s+capacity
```

Answer (score 0):

[How do I find all occurrences of a specific sentence within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220617/how-do-i-find-all-occurrences-of-a-specific-sentence-within-a-string) 
This may help. You can use a starting index to get the index from in IndexOf.
 index = str.IndexOf(text.Text, {index++ of previous find});

As @KSdev said, you are getting the same index everytime.

Comment: David Scott why not increment index by the length of the found text ´index = index + text.Text.legth´

Answer (score 0):

Just a small tweak on the answer by Mauricio Gracia that uses LINQ:

```
        int max = wordslist.Count;
        //find all the indexes using LINQ
        List<int> matches = Enumerable.Range(0, wordslist.Count)
                        .Where(i => wordslist[i] == text.Text)
                        .ToList();

        foreach( int match in matches ) {                
                if(match - 1 > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + wordslist[match - 1]+ " " + text.Text);
                }

                if (match + 1 < max)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + text.Text + " " + wordslist[match + 1]);
                }
        }
```