# C# Hangman IndexOf Loop

Tags: c#, indexof

I am a beginner in C# and i am trying to make a "hangman" game. I got stuck at the process when the player guess a letter.

If the word for example is DATA, the application only gets the first A in DATA. 
I understand that i have to loop the word to get all the A´s but i am having touble with making it work!

here is my code for the method myGuess:

```
public void myGuess(String letter)
{
        int plats = 0;

        string wordToGuess = label4.Text;

        plats = wordToGuess.IndexOf(letter);

        string wordToShow = label5.Text;
        //ersätt "_" med bokstaven på alla positioner bokstaven dyker upp

        wordToShow = wordToShow.Substring(0, wordToGuess.IndexOf(letter)) + letter +
                     wordToShow.Substring(plats + 1, wordToShow.Length - (plats + 1));

        label5.Text = wordToShow;  
}
```

I have been trying to google it but because i am a beginner i don't understand the 
suggestions people give. Hopefully it is a way to loop for more than one letter with IndexOf?

Comment: Your code seems to be incompletely pasted.

Comment: what's the purpose of the myGuess function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find all occurrences of a specific sentence within a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220617/how-do-i-find-all-occurrences-of-a-specific-sentence-within-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

IndexOf returns the index of the first instance of the character in the string.  You could manipulate your string using substring, but you'd be making it more complicated than you need to need.  Instead, you can just loop through each of the characters in the String with a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.Length; i++ )
{
    if (WordToGuess[i] == letter)
    {
         //Update the correctly guessed letters, (using value of i to determine which letter to make visible.)
    }
}
label5.Text = wordToShow;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
label4(wordToGuess): DATA
label5(wordToShow):  ****
```

When you call myGuess('A')

```
label4(wordToGuess): DATA
label5(wordToShow):  *A*A
```

When you call myGuess('T')

```
label4(wordToGuess): DATA
label5(wordToShow):  *ATA
```

...

```
public void myGuess(char letter)
    {
        string wordToGuess = label4.Text;
        string wordToShow = label5.Text;

        if (wordToShow.Length == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.Length; i++)
                wordToShow += "*";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.Length; i++)
        {
            if (wordToGuess[i] == letter || wordToGuess[i] == wordToShow[i])
                wordToShow = wordToShow.Remove(i,1).Insert(i, Char.ToString(letter));
        }

        label5.Text = wordToShow;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it works when I for ex. choose the letter 'A' in DATA, but if I then try to pick letter T, the _A_A turns in to _TTA, so it removes the "earlier" index too?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a long solution that's probably overly generic.

```
List<int> findIndexes(string myStr, char letter)
{
    var foundIndexes = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myStr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (myStr[i] == letter)
        foundIndexes.Add(i);
    }
    return foundIndexes;
}
string ReplaceIndex(string s, int index, char letter){
    return s.Substring(0, index ) 
    + letter 
    + s.Substring(index + 1, s.Length - (index + 1));
}
void Main()
{
    string s= "data";
    string wordToShow = "____";
    var letter = 'a';
    var indexes = findIndexes(s, letter);
    foreach (var index in indexes)
    {
        wordToShow = ReplaceIndex(wordToShow, index, letter);
    }
    Console.WriteLine (wordToShow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop should handle it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.Length; i++)
{
    if (wordToGuess[i].ToString().Equals(letter.ToString(), System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        wordToShow = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", wordToShow.Substring(0, i), letter, wordToShow.Substring(i, wordToShow.Length - (i + 1)));
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/UATeVJ